# How to show the SelectedItem of the ListPicker?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I dunno how to get/show/display the item that is selected now in the `ListPicker`. Is there anyway to do this ? If i run my below C# Code, the app breaks. I dunno why.

XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker
    x:Name="categoriesListPicker"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectionChanged="categoriesListPicker_SelectionChanged">
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void categoriesListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = categoriesListPicker.SelectedItem as string;
        MessageBox.Show(selectedItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wen the application fires, nothing is selected. I think your application is breaking on that.
Before you get the selected item and parse it to a string you should check whether nothing is "null"

Try this:

```
private void categoriesListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (categoriesListPicker.SelectedItem != null)
    {
                string selectedItem = categoriesListPicker.SelectedItem as string;
                MessageBox.Show(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, you should debug the application and try to find out which line breaks your applications. In addition, please provide the error that is thrown.

Comment: the app breaks. i have mentioned it in my question itself. please explain your answer in code.

Comment: eddit my post with code snippet, now it checks whether the selected item is not null

Comment: even now. the app breaks. it mentions `MessageBox.Show(selectedItem);` this as the reason. i think selectedItem is not the `string`

Comment: So when you remove the `MessageBox.Show(selectedItem);` your aplication doesn't break? If so, are you sure that this messagebox is available on windows phone?

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark it as the correct one